# Calling php code from php code on different server

Tags: php, web-services, curl, phpunit

The situation is following. I have a local (development) PHP server (Win + IIS) on my computer and I would like to call a function on a remote server because there is an executable file on the remote server (linux) that does not run on my local computer.
So on the remote server would be a simple PHP page which calls the executable with given parameters and returns the results.
I can imagine making an ajax call from javascript to this remote PHP page, but in my case I am using PHPUnit locally and at one point I need to call this remote page for specific data (which the executable file provides).
So my question is - how to make a call from PHP (local) to PHP (remote)? Is web-services the way to go or can this be accomplished simpler?

Comment: Seeing the phpunit tag I would also recommend to have a stub for this remote data and a config switch to enable/disable use of the stub.

Comment: Yes, after I wrote this, I also started to think about stub-ing / mocking this out...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$output = file_get_contents('http://your.remote.server/page.php?args=12345');
```

Or you can use cURL. Keep in mind that when you're executing files in PHP you should limit the ability for other people to do so(ie. password protect the page/directory) and escape the shell arguments before running them.

Answer (score 1):

```
$param['one'] = 1;
$param['two'] = 2;
file_get_contents("http://example.com/service.php?".http_build_query($param));
```

Comment: that function is actually http_build_query() - http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [PHP cURL library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to query scripts on remote servers.

Answer (score 0):

Use [fopen](http://il2.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) or [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to call your remote script.